# Add a non Gradle Project to a Gradle Multiproject as Module in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

- Project A is a Gradle multi project with the sub projects b and c.
- Project X is a non Gradle project. The sub projects depend on (compiled) project X.
- The Project X jar is included as file tree dependency in the
  build.gradle of the sub projects:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: project.projectDir.path + '/lib/', include: ['X.jar])
```

As IDE we are using Intellij. We want to have project A and X in the same workspace and we want to have changes made in project X to be reflected on the classpath of Project A.

We tried to add project X to A,b,c in the Module Settings in Intellij as dependency without success.

Is there a way to achive the described scenario in Intellij without migrating project X to gradle?

Comment: Even if there is, there is a good chance that the solution isn't robust, and will cause you trouble again and again over time. Don't fight tools, don't do things that aren't "intended" / "mainstream". Meaning, imho: rather invest more time now, and turn X into a gradle project.

Comment: Sure, we will do that. But unfortunately we are currently  in the middle of a migration phase. So we would need a temporarly solution until we will have migrated all our projects.